# If $u(0,t)=0$ then does $u_t(0,t)=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

This came up while I was working with PDEs. What I'm asking isn't part of the question itself but it would definitely simplify my work if it was true.

So if I had some function $u(x,t), x\in [0,l], t>0$, where $u(0,t)=0~ \forall t>0$ then can I also say that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(0,t)=0$?

And also, if $u(l,t)=0~\forall t$ then is it true that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(l,t)=0$?

I couldn't think of any examples to disprove it but I also don't think I've really come across this before.

(For more details: The PDE I'm working with is sort of a wave equation (with some extra terms). And it's said in the question that the initial conditions of the PDE also satisfy the boundary conditions. So $u(0,0)=0$ and $u(l,0)=0$ is already known. I'm just wondering about the rest of $t$).

Comment: It looks from your notation that $x=0$ is outside the domain of $u$.  Did you mean instead that $x \in [0,l]$ rather than $(0,l)$?

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd edited. thanks.

Comment: If $u(0,t)=0\forall t>0$, then the partial differential of $u(0,t)$ with respect to $t$ is $0$, for any function $u(0,t)$. If $u(l,t)=0$, then it is not necessary that the partial differential of $u(l,t)$ with respect to $t$ is $0$, as we do not know if that zero is just at the point $(l,t)$, or for all $t$.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar I forgot to put it originally but on my homework it did say that $u(l,t)=0$ **for all** $t$. I'm not sure if that's what you were getting at. I'm using $t$ as my time variable, it's not a specific point.

Comment: If $u(l,t)=0\forall t$, then the partial differential of $u(l,t)$ w.r.t. $t$ is $0$ - can you see why? I understand that $t$ is used as a time variable - I am a gravitational physicist!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. Taking the partial with respect to $t$ is akin to treating $x$ as a constant. If $x$ is fixed at $0$ the function $f(t) = u(0,t)$ is a constant, hence the derivative $f'(t) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\mid_{x=0}=0$